# Functions aren't running

Tags: python, python-3.x

My functions in Python aren't returning values that I expect them to. Here is a MWE:

```
a = 6
b = 18
c = 0
def random_function(c):
    c = b/a
    return c

random_function(c)
print(c)
```

I expect this function to print 3, but instead it prints 0. I have just updated from 2.7 to 3.6 and this would have worked in 2.7 - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have two entirely separate variables named `c` here - the local variable (actually a parameter) inside `random_function()`, and the global variable of the same name.  There is ABSOLUTELY NO CONNECTION between the two - passing the global `c` as the value for the `c` parameter does not create any such connection.

Comment: This would have worked **exactly the same** in Python 2, although, your `random_function` would have returned something different, due to the difference in the `/` operator, but `print(c)` will print `0` in both.

Comment: Declare `c` to be global with a `global c` statement at the beginning of the function. Variables created inside functions are local by default. A better alternative would be to assign the return value to the outer `c` variable explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to store returned value from method.

```
a = 6
b = 18
c = 0
def random_function(c):
    c = b/a
    return c

c= random_function(c)
print(c)
```

Comment: You probably should choose a different name to assign the return value to - so the original `c` doesn't *disappear*.

Comment: This is ***not*** the best answer of the three. Either of the other two is more complete.

Answer (score 2):

As @Dharmesh said, you need to store the value of `c` when it comes out of `random_function()`.

*i.e.* `c = random_function(c)`

**The Reason:**

Scope is everything. When you change the value of `c` from within the function, it only affects the value of `c` within the scope of that function and doesn't change its value in the global context.

In order for the value you assigned to `c` from within the function to be preserved, you need to assign `c` the value returned by the function.

Answer (score 0):

you are printing c value which was assigned globally.

```
a = 6
b = 18
c = 0
def random_function(c):
    c = b/a
    return c    # -- this variable scope is local

random_function(c)
print(c)     #--  prints Global variable
```

to print as you expected, you need to change your function call like below

```
print (random_function(c))
```

or

```
c = random_function(c)  # this will re assign global value of 'c' with function return value 
print(c)
```